# App bar menu items not opening correct sub menu

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am building a front-end application using React16 and the Material UI library.

I am trying to build a simple navigation bar at the top containing multiple menu items. I took the "simple menu" example from the material-ui.com website.

I tried to add a second menu item in the app bar.

However, clicking on either one of the menu items opens the sub-menus for `profile-menu`. So in other words clicking on `simple-menu` opens up Profile, My Account, and Logout but it should open up New, List, and Report.

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import AccountCircle from '@material-ui/icons/AccountCircle';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Menu from '@material-ui/core/Menu';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  menuButton: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
  },
  title: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
}));

function MenuAppBar() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [auth, setAuth] = React.useState(true);
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);

  function handleMenu(event) {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  }

  function handleClose() {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  }

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <AppBar color="default" position="static">
        <Toolbar>
          <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.title}>
            App
          </Typography>
          {auth && (
            <div>
              <Button
                aria-owns={anchorEl ? 'simple-menu' : undefined}
                aria-haspopup="true"
                onClick={handleMenu}
              >
                Open Menu
              </Button>
              <Menu id="simple-menu" anchorEl={anchorEl} open={Boolean(anchorEl)} onClose={handleClose}>
                <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>New</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>List</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Report</MenuItem>
              </Menu>
            </div>
          )}
          {auth && (
            <div>
              <IconButton
                aria-owns={anchorEl ? 'profile-menu' : undefined}
                aria-haspopup="true"
                onClick={handleMenu}
              >
              <AccountCircle />
              </IconButton>
              <Menu id="profile-menu" anchorEl={anchorEl} open={Boolean(anchorEl)} onClose={handleClose}>
                <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>My account</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Logout</MenuItem>
              </Menu>
            </div>
          )}
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MenuAppBar;
```

Comment: you should define the open as a constant type that you map to. So for instance `open={!!anchorEl && anchorEl === 'profile'}` just fyi, `!!` is a better boolean check than the type constructor `Boolean`

Comment: @JohnRuddell Thanks! Tried that but it doesn't seem to work. Now neither menu opens. ` <Menu id="simple-menu" anchorEl={anchorEl} open={!!anchorEl && anchorEl === 'simple-menu'} onClose={handleClose}>` .

Comment: let me write up a solution, because you have to apply the same value to anchorEl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to define the menus in an enum / object

```
const MenuTypes = Object.freeze({
    Simple: 'simple',
    Profile: 'profile'
})
```

Add another state item to track your active menu

```
const [activeMenu, setActiveMenu] = React.useState(null);
```

then update `handleMenu` to accept the menu type and set it in state. 
I can't remember off the top of my head if the menuType will be the first or second argument so verify this.

```
function handleMenu(menuType, event) {
  setActiveMenu(menuType);
  setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
}
```

Then your click callbacks need to reflect the correct menu

```
<Button
  aria-owns={anchorEl ? 'simple-menu' : undefined}
  aria-haspopup="true"
  onClick={handleMenu.bind(null, MenuTypes.Simple}
>
```

Then you need to reference that type to determine which is currently active

```
open={!!activeMenu && activeMenu === MenuTypes.Simple}
```

Dont forget to update the close handler as well

```
function handleClose() {
  setActiveMenu(null);
  setAnchorEl(null);
}
```

Let me know if anything here doesn't make sense and I'll try and explain in more detail what is confusing :)

Comment: Thanks! I am now seeing this error: `index.js:1375 Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `anchorEl` supplied to `ForwardRef(Menu)` I confirmed that menuType is the first argument and it shows the correct value in console.log.

Comment: What is the anchorEl supposed to be? Meaning the prop that Menu wants? Probably need to do what you were doing before in terms of storing the currentTarget along side these changes

Comment: @pengz let me update my answer you need to keep track of both actually

Comment: @pengz give that a shot